# iOS -Setting ScrollView Current Page

Tags: ios, scrollview, tableview, uislider, cgpoint

I am working on a project in which I need a scrollview to show a number of images and I allow user to set a definite picture from scrollview as a favorite one and save favorites in tableview In order to get it again as user wish .

My problem is concerning setting scrollview current page by a value returned from selecting a row cell in tableview

Now this is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;

    PagedScrollViewController *paged = [PagedScrollViewController alloc];

    NSString *page_str = [str substringFromIndex:9];

    int page_number = [page_str intValue];

    [paged.slider setValue: page_number] ;

    [paged.current_page_lbl setText:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",page_number ]];

    int page = paged.slider.value ;

    NSLog(@"go to page %d",page_number);

    CGPoint pnt = CGPointMake((page-1) * paged.scrollView.frame.size.width , 0) ;
    [paged.scrollView setContentOffset:pnt animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"point is %d",pnt);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

ScrollView page do not changed when back from tableview

also CGPoint point returned a negative value do not changed ever ! What is the problem with that ?!

===========

I still need help :

how to update the scrollview when returning from tableview with a definite page number ?!

[this is my storyboard](http://www.imageshack.us/f/204/screenshotatq.png)

Comment: I think you need to initialize `paged` (not just `alloc` it). Also, set breakpoints and see if both `paged` and `page` are what you want them to be.

Comment: thanks I tried to initiate paged but no change happened , page returns a right number but what do you mean with check - paged - what is expected ?!

Comment: oh, wait, i think I got it. You are creating a new `PagedScrollViewController` instance, but are you adding it (as a subview) anywhere? What do you mean by "ScrollView page do not changed when back from tableview" ? It's because you're changing the slider value of the NEW `PagedScrollViewController` that you just created, but NOT the `PagedScrollViewController` that's already there.

Comment: also, the reason `pnt` returns negative values is that `paged.scrollView.frame` is probably not set.

Comment: I do not need to add any subview , all what I need when choosing row cell with text "photo no 5" to return to PagedScrollViewController and set scrollview content to picture no 5 . How I can do that ?!

Comment: Is your `PagedScrollViewController` created in the XIB file or in code? if in XIB, create an outlet for it and use it to change the slider values etc.

Comment: ok , but Is it needed to be connected as an outlet ? connected with what ?? BTW I am using storyboard and PagedScrollViewController is a UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> .

Comment: ok, let's start at the beginning. Is your `PagedScrollViewController` the root view controller? and so is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` inside the `PagedScrollViewController.m` file?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is in another TableViewController which contains favorites list of pictures .

Comment: this is my storyboard http://imageshack.us/f/204/screenshotatq.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `TableViewController`, create an outlet to your PageScrollViewController (the one in XIB). Call the outlet myPaged or something.

Then, inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you can use `myPaged` instead of `paged`. (take out the line where you are creating a new instance of `PageScrollViewController`).

for example:

```
[myPaged.slider setValue: page_number];
```

will change the the slider of your `PageScrollViewController` in the XIB file (the one you want).

Comment: will PageScrollViewController outlet need to be connected ? connected with what ?!

Comment: I did that but nothing changed ):

Comment: do you have your outlet set? That is, does `myPaged` point to your PageScrollViewController?

Comment: search google for creating outlets from the xib file. Should be pretty straightforward (and essential for most apps)...

Comment: how could my paged which is an outlet in another controller can point out to PageScrollViewController ?! I cannot get you .

Comment: don't use paged. forget it. Instead, create an outlet called myPaged that points to PageScrollViewController. Use myPaged in your code to change the slider values.

Comment: I already did that and nothing changed .. so I asked Is the new outlet need to be connected with any thing ?!

Comment: the outlet variable (called myPaged) has to be connected to the PageScrollViewController in the xib. (check google on how to do it)